# Mysql strange query cost on OR

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

By some reason those 2 equivalent queries have largely different costs.

```
select p.*
from properties p
where owner_phone = '+598 99 554 718'
    or p.id in (
        select pop.property 
        from property_other_phones pop
        where pop.phone='+598 99 554 718'
    )
```

Has the following costs:
[image]

While this other one:

```
select p.*
from properties p
where
    p.id in (
        select id
        from properties
        where owner_phone = '+1 781-953-6380'
    )

union select p.*
from properties p
where
    p.id in (
        select pop.property 
        from property_other_phones pop
        where pop.phone='+1 781-953-6380'
    )
```

Has this completely different cost:
[image]

Do you guys have some clue ?

Conext: MySQL 5.7.16

Comment: The queries don't look the same to me.

Comment: The results returned by the two queries may appear to be equivalent, but the two queries look *different* to MySQL Historically, MySQL has continued the tradition of generating less than ideal plans for queries with `OR` predicates.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, the MySQL optimizer generates suboptimal plans for queries with `OR` predicates. Which is why we frequently use UNION/UNION ALL subqueries in place of `OR` predicates.

The question suggests that the two queries are equivalent. I agree that the results returned by the two query patterns may appear to be equivalent. But the two query patterns are significantly different, in terms of the way the MySQL optimizer looks at them, and what operations are available to the optimizer.

For the two queries shown in the question, the execution plan selected by the MySQL optimizer for each query looks to be par for the course. (The generated plan for the `OR` query may be less than ideal. That may be unfortunate, but it's not really "strange".)

Assuming that `id` is the primary key (or a unique key) on `properties`, I would opt for a query pattern like this:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM properties p
  JOIN ( SELECT i.id
           FROM properties i
          WHERE i.owner_phone = '+1 781-953-6380'
          UNION
         SELECT pop.property AS id
           FROM property_other_phones pop
          WHERE pop.phone     = '+1 781-953-6380'
       ) q
    ON q.id = p.id
```

As another alternative, I might consider:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM properties p
 WHERE p.owner_phone         = '+1 781-953-6380'
 UNION ALL
SELECT q.*
  FROM properties q
  JOIN property_other_phones pop
    ON pop.property = q.id
 WHERE pop.phone             = '+1 781-953-6380'
   AND NOT ( q.owner_phone <=> '+1 781-953-6380')
```

Comment: Thanks!, checked the suggestions and worked perfectly. I still do not fully understand the reason for the Full Table Scan in the first query :(, if you can throw some light on this will be appreciated.

Comment: `OR` leads to a full table scan. The trick spencer used was to turn the `OR` into `UNION`; each part of it could run quite efficiently.

Comment: @Ignacio: the MySQL optimizer is limited; it can only choose a single index to use for the access. For the first condition, MySQL could use an index range scan to satisfy the `owner_phone =` predicate. But that index doesn't really help with the `id IN ()` predicate... to check that MySQL would need to evaluate every row. Conversely, if MySQL chooses to use an index with leading column of id to locate the rows that satisfy the second condition, there's still the first condition to deal with... and we're back to checking every row. If MySQL has to check every flipping row, it's a full scan ...

Comment: I think MySQL might be able to do a full index scan, rather than a table scan (that's just a guess) if there is an index that contains both `id` and `owner_phone`. But that's still a full scan. We can avoid the full scan if we break the query into two queries (two SELECT). With that, MySQL can optimize each of those separately, and can use the most appropriate index for each. Then we can tell MySQL to use a UNION or UNION ALL operation to combine the results from the two SELECT. So, its Equivalent to the `OR`, but working around the limitation in the optimizer.